# Nativescript (typescript) How do I access/get the instance/reference of a component from a different component?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to access the component(Class instance) of NavigationButton and SearchBar in ActionBar from the component(Class instance) of a tabItem in a TabView. How do I do this?

```
<ActionBar color="black" title="">
    <NavigationButton #navBtn text="Go Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" (tap)="goBack()" [visibility]="navBtnVisibility"></NavigationButton>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="tabIndex == 0" titleView orientation="horizontal">
        <SearchBar hint="Search hint" [text]="searchPhrase" (textChange)="onTextChanged($event)" (submit)="onSubmit($event)" 
        color="black" textFieldHintColor="black"></SearchBar>
    </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>

<TabView #tabView [selectedIndex]="tabIndex" (selectedIndexChanged)="tabViewIndexChange(tabView.selectedIndex)">
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Search'}" class="tab-item">
        <search-tab>
        </search-tab>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Home'}" class="tab-item">
        <home-tab>
        </home-tab>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Profile'}" class="tab-item">
        <!--<profile></profile>-->
        <profile-tab>
        </profile-tab>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

Comment: You should use a Subject  from the parent component and subscribe to that in your tab component classes in order for them to get  notified that the search text changes for the example or the nav button was clicked. Don't forget to unsubscribe once when you are navigateing between tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Possible way to accomplish this is to use a service, bind your references from the Parent Component, and then in your child components you should inject the service.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using `ViewChild` / `ContentChild` or even services. But an easiest way I could be by accessing the frame package,

```
const currentPage = frame.topmost().currentPage
```

Once you get the current page, you can access it's action bar or any component residing inside the page.

Comment: what `frame` did you mean? I work on nativescript angular and doing this `import { Frame } from "tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame";` but does not work

Comment: It should be just `import * as frame from "tns-core-modules/ui/frame";`

Answer (score 0):

Component to component communication only happens between direct parent-child relationships in Angular 2+.  Otherwise you must use an Angular service as a go-between.

So, the pictured component could access ActionBar and TabView with @ViewChild(), and the ActionBar component could access NavigationButton with @ContentChild() since NavigationButton is between `<ActionBar>`and `</ActionBar>,` but grandparent, sibling, and cousin relationships require a service go-between.

AngularJS had $parent.$parent.$parent stuff but it was deprecated by style guides for poor architecture.